# random unique integers avoid duplicates before insert

Tags: sqlite

Given a need to store 4 digit random unique integers, how would I do a efficient insert of a large quality new numbers.

If the values are created outside sqlite there's a chance the values already existing in the database

What would be the best method to do such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the column where the numbers will be stored UNIQUE and use INSERT OR IGNORE on a SINGLE INSERT with multiple values (for efficiency). e.g. :-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO rndm_id VALUES
  ('0001'),('0027'),('9999'),('0412'),('2108'),
  ('0001'), -- duplicate will be skipped
  ('3085') -- and so on
;
```

Note values have been enclosed in quotes to maintain 4 numerics. The Table was defined using :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rndm_id (myid TEXT UNIQUE);
```

If you are considering a large number of values then may need to consider :-

> **Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement**
>
> The maximum number of bytes in the text of an SQL statement is limited
>   to SQLITE_MAX_SQL_LENGTH which defaults to 1000000. You can redefine
>   this limit to be as large as the smaller of SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH and
>   1073741824.
>
> If an SQL statement is limited to be a million bytes in length, then
>   obviously you will not be able to insert multi-million byte strings by
>   embedding them as literals inside of INSERT statements. But you should
>   not do that anyway. Use host parameters for your data. Prepare short
>   SQL statements like this:
>
> INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(?,?,?); Then use the sqlite3_bind_XXXX()
>   functions to bind your large string values to the SQL statement. The
>   use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the
>   string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is also runs
>   faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as
>   much.
>
> The maximum length of an SQL statement can be lowered at run-time
>   using the sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_SQL_LENGTH,size) interface.
>   [Limits In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Considering the comment

> *Is there a way I can do a select to give a a set of new values which I
>   can use then do a insert later?*

So assuming that you wanted 1000 4 digit  unique random values then the following may suffice :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS save_for_later; -- Drop the table
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS save_for_later (four_digit_random_value UNIQUE); -- Create a temporary table

-- Create a table with 1500 random rows 
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (
    SELECT CAST((abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)) AS TEXT)
    UNION ALL SELECT CAST((abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)) AS TEXT)
    FROM cte1 LIMIT 1500
    )
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO save_for_later SELECT * FROM cte1;

-- Later on extract the 1000 required rows.
SELECT * FROM save_for_later LIMIT 1000;
```

### Suspected requirement

If the question were ***how can I insert a set number (300) of random 4 numeric unique values into a table (master) with existing data where the new values should also be unique in conjunction with the existing values***

Then the following could do that (see note re limitations) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master; -- 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master (random_value TEXT UNIQUE);

-- Master (existing) Table populated with some values
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO master VALUES
  ('0001'),('0027'),('9999'),('0412'),('2108'),
  ('0001'), -- duplicate will be skipped
  ('3085') -- and so on
;
SELECT * FROM master; -- Result 1 show what's in the master table

-- Create a table to save the values for later
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS save_for_later; -- Drop the table
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS save_for_later (four_digit_random_value UNIQUE); -- Create a temporary table

-- Populate the vales to be saved for later excluding any values that already exist
-- 1500 rows perhaps excessive but very likely to result in 300 unique values
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(rndm) AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST((abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)) AS TEXT)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        CAST((abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)||abs(random() % 10)) AS TEXT) 
    FROM cte1 
    LIMIT 1500 --<<<<<< LIMIT important otherwise would be infinite
    )
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO save_for_later 
        SELECT * FROM cte1 
            WHERE rndm NOT IN(SELECT * FROM master)
;

-- Later on extract the required rows (300 here) and insert them.
INSERT INTO master
    SELECT * FROM save_for_later 
    LIMIT 300;

SELECT * FROM master; -- Should be 6 original/existing rows + 300 so 306 rows (although perhaps a chance that 300 weren't generated)
```

- Note with 4 numerics there is a limitation of 10,000 possible values (0000-9999), so the more values that exist in the original table the greater the chance that there will be issues finding values that would be unique.

The above would result in :-

The first result the master table before generation of the new values :-

[image]

The result after adding the new values (original 6 rows + new 300 rows) :-

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can do a select to give a a set of new values which I can use then do a insert later?

Comment: @moimoi probably yes for example using WITH RECURSIVE, but that would be a completely different question, considering you saying *If the values are created outside sqlite*